# Guardar en un Array[] nombres de archivos de una carpeta en C#

Tags: c#, array

¿Como guardar los nombres de archivos en un array?
Al abrir el Open File Dialog que se obtenga la ruta y en un array se guarde todos los nombres de imágenes o archivos.

Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza el método [`GetFiles()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2) de la clase `Directory`.

Este te va a devolver un arreglo con todos los archivos que coincidan con el criterio de búsqueda, por ejemplo:

```
ruta = @"c:\users\juan\documents";
string[] archivos = Directory.GetFiles(ruta, "*.jpg");
```

Me va a devolver todos los archivos con extensión `.jpg` que estén en mi carpeta de documentos.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes usar `OpenFileDialog` para obtener un ruta, para eso se usa el `FolderBrowserDialog`

```
string[] arrayNombres;

using(var folderBrowserDialog1 = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog();
    if( result == DialogResult.OK )
    {
        string folderName = folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath;

        arrayNombres = Directory.GetFiles(folderName, "*.*");
    }
}
```

Usando `Directory.GetFiles()` obtienes los archivos de la carpeta

[Cómo: Elegir carpetas con el componente FolderBrowserDialog de formularios Windows Forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-choose-folders-with-the-windows-forms-folderbrowserdialog-component)